# Notify clients after AWS lambda function execution

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an app using angular on the frontend and AWS as the backend and I need to add some functionalities that will consume data from an external source.

I've written a Lambda Function which will be scheduled to run at every X minutes and should perform the following steps:

1. Retrieve data from the external source
2. Process data
3. Store processed data on own DB
4. Notify clients (frontends) that new info is available

The issue is on how to perform step 4.

I've been researching for a while, and found some AWS services that could be used, but still none seems to be the exact match for that.

The main one is AWS AppSync, but it sounds like an overkill, as I only need simple notifications.

There are also some AWS IOT services, but this seems to be off topic.

There is also AWS Simple Notification Service, but AFAIK it only works for notifying other services (via POST requests).

Would any of these services be the right one for this use case? If not, which would be a suitable AWS service for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Webhooks with AWS SNS, which can then further inform your webapp via socket realtime.

AWS document: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-http-https-endpoint-as-subscriber.html

[flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ov7xk.png)

Comment: Not sure if I got your point. How would I push notifications to the clients using this architecture?

Comment: You need to read about SNS, topic and subscribing to the topic

Comment: @Neo thanks for the answer and the flow! The point is that I don't have a server, all the backend is based on a microservices, background as service, architecture. So I'm not looking for writing and hosting a server only for setting up a web socket. I would like to use an AWS service for that as I've been using for other areas: API Gateway for building the API, Lambda for processing, S3 for files, Cognito for authentication, and so on.

Comment: If you are using API Gateway as web api for your client, You can create websocket APIs with same, if you would like to check: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-websocket-apis-in-amazon-api-gateway/. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thanks again, @Neo! Will check that and get back.

Answer (score 0):

Your client can get data in a few ways:

Pull - check an API endpoint for new records periodically. You will have more requests than necessary but it will be easy to implement.

Push - bidirectional, have a socket connection that will push updated to your client. That's essentially what AppSync subscriptions is, it might seem like an overkill, but it's easier than the alternative WebSocket APIs in Amazon API Gateway https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-websocket-apis-in-amazon-api-gateway/.

Comment: Dani, thanks for your answer! The pull alternative is surely the easiest one to implement, but it will waste more resources and still not have an as good user experience as it could be. API Gateway WS api is something I was not aware before @Neo comment. It seems a good alternative, but I would still need to keep track of the connectionId of each client individually (which is not a big issue, but also not desirable). I'm still looking for a simpler solution.